# Regex in c# including comments

Tags: c#, regex, comments

I have a string:

```
String str = { { /*start address*/ 0x00004200, /*Length*/ 0x00003CBF } , { /*start address*/ 0x00004200, /*Length*/ 0x00003CBF } };
```

I need to validate the above string using a regex.

The regex which I have written is:

```
^{ *{ *([/*]{1} *(\S* *)* *[*/]{1} *)?(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{1,8}, *([/*]{1} *(\S* *)* *[*/]{1} *)?(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{1,8} *} *( *,\s*{ *([/*]{1} *(\S* *)* *[*/]{1} *)?(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{1,8}, *([/*]{1} *(\S* *)* *[*/]{1} *)?(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{1,8} *})*\s*} *;$
```

I know its a bit complex. I am not able to get it right. Application just crashes at the Regex.Match line.

I think the issue is with having /* and */ in between the string and regex w.r.t that is not correct.

Comment: Try debugging it at https://www.debuggex.com/, where you can enter a regexp and see a visual representation of it, and enter data to test it against. It's much easier than trying to do it in C#.

Comment: Thank you Matthew. I tried the tool. But I am unable to understand its working.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I could use the tool and work out another regex. Thanks for sharing the tool reference. It was of great help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex like below.

```
^{ *{( *[/*]{2} *(?:(?!/\*|\*/).)*\*/ *(?:0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{1,8} *)(?:, *[/*]{2} *(?:(?!/\*|\*/).)*\*/ *(?:0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{1,8} *)} *, *{ *[/*]{2} *(?:(?!/\*|\*/).)*\*/ *(?:0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{1,8} *, *[/*]{2} *(?:(?!/\*|\*/).)*\*/ *(?:0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{1,8} *} *};$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hC0qA9/5)

Comment: Thanks Avinash. I tried ur code. But got an exception: "Unrecognized grouping construct".

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
string txt="{ { /*start address*/ 0x00004200, /*Length*/ 0x00003CBF } , { /*start address*/ 0x00004200, /*Length*/ 0x00003CBF } }";

string re1="(\\{)"; // Any Single Character 1
string re2=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
string re3="(\\/\\*[\\d\\D]*?\\*\\/)";  // C Comment 1

Regex r = new Regex(re1+re2+re3,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
Match m = r.Match(txt);
```